# Spivak's calculus question Q1-14 part b: $-b\leq a\leq b\iff|a|\leq b$ using $-|a|\leq a\leq |a|$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification, proof-writing

> Prove that $—b \leq a \leq b$ if and only if $|a| \leq b$. In particular, it follows
> that $— |a| \leq a \leq |a|$.

There are multiple answers to this question but none employed Spivak's hint.
[Spivak's Calculus: Ch. 1, Problem 14 (absolute value inequality)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2702808/spivaks-calculus-ch-1-problem-14-absolute-value-inequality) or [Prove that $|a| < b \iff -b<a<b$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/538795/prove-that-a-b-iff-bab)

I am self-studying Spivaks and I have no formal training in proof-writing, so the proof might be very shaky.

I used the hint for the "if" condition,

"if" part:

if $|a|\leq b$, it follows that $b\geq0$ and thus $b=|b|$

From the hint, $-|a|<a<|a| --(1)$.

Let $u$ be a real constant, by triangle inequality,

$|a|\leq |a|+|u| \leq |a+u| --(2)$.
and so, $-|a|\geq -|a+u| -- (3)$

Substituting (2) and (3) into (1), $-|a+u|\leq|a|\leq|a+u|$. With the substitution $b=a+u$, $-|b|\leq a\leq|b|$

For the "only if" part,

By means of contradiction, suppose $b<0$, and let $b'$ be a positive number such that $b'=-b$, the inequality can be written as $b'\leq a \leq -b'$ which does not make sense as $b'$ can never be less than $-b'$. Therefore, $b>0$

Since $-b \leq a \leq b$, $a^2 \leq b^2$, since $a^2$ and $b^2$ are positive, so $\sqrt{a^2} < \sqrt{b^2} \Rightarrow |a|<|b|$

Since $b>0$, $|a|<b$

□

> I am quite sure "only if" part is correct. But I am unsure of my "if" part. Is the proof acceptable? Is the use of Spivak's hint appropriate?

Thank you for responding!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first part is wrong; you are using the opposite of the triangle inequality, which is false.

What you were expected to do is to notice that $|a|≤b$ implies $-b≤-|a|$. Then
$$
-b≤-|a|≤a≤|a|≤b.
$$

The proof of the converse is
correct, but it unnecessarily complicated. You have $-b≤a≤b$. If $a≥0$, then $|a|=a≤ b$. If $a<0$, then $|a|=-a≤b$ (from $-b≤a$).

Comment: Ah… I see what you mean. Thank you